# How do you set the content type for a WebMatrix/Razor Response?

Tags: content-type, webmatrix, razor

I'd like to return some XML instead of HTML in my WebMatrix cshtml file? How do you change the content type header?

Comment: I just had to figure this out so I'm posting for others to find the answer in the future.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the Response.ContentType property at the top of your .cshtml file then include the XML in the content of the view:

```
@{ 
   Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>415-123-4567</Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: Wow!! You edited your answer to match mine rather than select mine as the accepted answer?? That's cold, man... ice cold. (Check the revisions everybody)

Comment: It's a wiki, you should have proposed an edit or commented on this one. Mine got out of date, so I updated it.

Answer (score 19):

At the top of your Razor file, set the ContentType of the Response object:

```
@{
  Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
}
... xml here ...
```

Comment: At the time I wrote the other answer (first beta) that property wasn't accessible. I'll try that out now, thanks!

Comment: @John if the above worked for you would you consider changing the accepted answer? The above is _possibly_ more correct, though both achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC, you can choose to make the change in your action method in the controller, like so:

```
public ActionResult MyAction() {
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    return View();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't apply to just plain .cshtml files outside of ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Thanks @JohnSheehan, I updated my answer to include that note.