# Trying to convert an old MVC 2.1 project to 3 or 4 but getting some errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have used the tool to convert older webform MVC projects to razor, it is found here
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx

I then used another tool to covert the aspx webform files to razor cshtml files and added them to the project.

The program compiles fine but when it is launched it complains 
   Error Type: loadXML
   Description: incorrect XML

Then none of the existing events are showing on the calendar either.

Here is the index view

```
@model dynamic
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title>Index</title>
        <script src="/Scripts/dhtmlxscheduler.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="/Scripts/dhtmlxscheduler.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body
            {
                height:100%;
                padding:0px;
                margin:0px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function init() {
                scheduler.config.xml_date = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%i";
                scheduler.init("scheduler_here", new Date(2014, 6, 1), "month");
                scheduler.load("/Calendar/Data");

                var dp = new dataProcessor("/Calendar/Save");
                dp.init(scheduler);
                dp.setTransactionMode("POST", false);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width:100%; height:100%;'>
            <div class="dhx_cal_navline">
                <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>
                <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>
                @*<div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab" style="right:204px;"></div>
                <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right:140px;"></div>*@ 
                <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="month_tab" style="right:6px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_header">
            </div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_data">
            </div>      
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can you see where this is messing up?  This is using the calendar plugin at http://scheduler-net.com/

Comment: Also need to remove that `runat="server"` from the `<head>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in another thread, the end result was that I need the following in one of my views

```
@{ 
    Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
}
```

found here [How do you set the content type for a WebMatrix/Razor Response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190584/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-for-a-webmatrix-razor-response)